# Ansible: How to delete a folder and file inside a directory in a single task?

Tags: ansible

I'm using Ansible 2.3.2.0 and am trying to delete a file and folder inside a directory in one task.

Right now I have this

```
tasks:

  - name: Removing existing war
    file:
      path: /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/app.war
      state: absent

  - name: Removing existing folder
    file:
      path: /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/app
      state: absent
```

I cannot simply remove the webapps folder because I do not want to delete other files and folders in there. I want to reduce the number of tasks because I am using Duo push auth and this adds to the deploy time. I've tried looping over files and file globs but for some reason it never works.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-files

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply iterate over the two values:

```
tasks:
  - name: Removing
    file:
      path: "{{ item }}"
      state: absent
    with_items:
      - /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/app.war
      - /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/app
```

But it will still create 2 tasks executions: one for each item.

Answer (score 5):

If you simply want to delete a directory and its contents, just use the **file** module and pass the path to the directory only:

```
tasks:
 - name: Removing
   file:
     path: /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/app
     state: absent
```

See this post: [Ansible: How to delete files and folders inside a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200732/ansible-how-to-delete-files-and-folders-inside-a-directory)

and from the ansible docs:

> If absent, directories will be recursively deleted, and files or symlinks will be unlinked.

see: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/file_module.html

Comment: The issue is that I DO NOT want to delete all files in the directory. I want to delete just one file and one directory in there.

Comment: oh I see.. app.war and app are both at the same level in webapps.. I should have looked at that closer. sorry. then @zigarn's answer is correct. use with_items to loop over the paths you want to remove.