# How to empty a directory using ansible

Tags: ansible

I have some directories and files inside a directory called `dir1`
I am trying to empty that directory using the below code

```
     - name: Clean  path
       file:
          state: absent
          path: "/home/location/dir1"
```

But it is deleting the `dir1` itself, i would like to empty it and keep this `dir1`, what am i missing here, any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: There are multiple approach on how to achieve this in this question: [Ansible: How to delete files and folders inside a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200732/ansible-how-to-delete-files-and-folders-inside-a-directory). The behaviour as you see it is the intended one, you want the directory to be absent, so it is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

To empty a directory you can use the [`shell`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html) module to run `rm` with a fileglob:

```yaml
- name: empty directory
  shell: rm -r /home/location/dir1/*
```

Note that if your directory contains hidden dotfiles, you'll need to explicitly remove those as well:

```yaml
- name: empty directory containing hidden files
  shell: rm -r /home/location/dir1/* /home/location/dir1/.*
```

---

Your provided task isn't doing what you want because you're declaring that the directory should be `absent`, so it gets completely removed rather than emptied.

The `command` module won't work for the `rm` because it will not expand file globs, resulting in an error like:

```
rm: cannot remove '/home/location/dir1/*': No such file or directory
```

Comment: I think there's some more Ansible-y ways to do this than just using the shell module. Lots of modules exist for file management in Ansible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a `command` instead.

```
- name: Clean path
    command: rm -r /home/location/dir1/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not remove the directory with the same task you're using, and re-add it immediately after using the same module? Seems like the most straightforward way to me. You could do some stuff with `fileglob` and `with_items` but that seems like over complicating a simple task.

```yaml
- name: Remove folder
  file:
    state: absent
    path: "/home/location/dir1"

- name: Re-make folder
  file:
    state: directory
    path: "/home/location/dir1"
```

Comment: Many reasons why not. For one thing, your snippet doesn't capture the ownership and permissions of the directory and re-use them.