# Ansible - remove w wildcard support

Tags: ansible

I'm writing code to let users delete several files at once.
The `file` module does not support wildcards, but I'd like that.

Currently I'm simply using the `shell` module to delete files, e.g:

```yaml
- name: delete file(s)
  shell: "rm {{ user_input }}"
```

In this case, `user_input` can be `/tmp/*/whatever`.

Comment: Oh, that already looks dangerous to me. Even if a construct [`with_fileglob`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fileglob_lookup.html#examples) would somehow work, as it is a lookup plugin, only on the Control Node. So, do not `- file:
        path: "{{ item }}"
        state: absent
      with_fileglob:
        - "{{ user_input }}"`

Comment: Because of the necessary input validation, error handling and catching up corner cases, your Use Case seems to fit best for a Custom Module written even in Bash or Python. Maybe you can get an idea from the answer under [File search between two dates with ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74614509/6771046).

Comment: An other approach might be to find the files to be deleted before, register them in a list and delete all files from the list. See in example [Ansible: How to delete files and folders inside a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51607074/6771046). But that will have because of multiple tasks and loops a much higher runtime.

Answer (score 2):

A better option is the command *find*, I think. For example, given the tree for testing

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/test
/tmp/test
├── dir1
│   ├── x
│   └── y
├── dir2
│   ├── x
│   ├── y
│   └── z
├── file1
└── file2
```

Get the pattern, find the files, and optionally ask if this is what you want to delete

```yaml
    - pause:
        prompt: Find pattern
      register: pattern

    - shell: "find {{ pattern.user_input }} -type f"
      register: files
      changed_when: false
      check_mode: false

    - pause:
        prompt: |-
          Do you want to delete [Y/N]?
            {% for file in files.stdout_lines %}
            {{ file }}
            {% endfor %}
      register: delete
      when: confirm|d(false)|bool
```

For example, try pattern `/tmp/test/*/x`

```yaml
TASK [pause] *******************************************************************************
[pause]
Find pattern:
/tmp/test/*/x^Mok: [localhost]

TASK [shell] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [pause] *******************************************************************************
[pause]
Do you want to delete [Y/N]?
    /tmp/test/dir1/x
    /tmp/test/dir2/x
  :
Y^Mok: [localhost]
```

The below task will delete the files if you either skip the confirmation or answer `Y`

```yaml
    - file:
        state: absent
        path: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ files.stdout_lines }}"
      when: delete.user_input|d('Y') == 'Y'
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - pause:
        prompt: Find pattern
      register: pattern

    - shell: "find {{ pattern.user_input }} -type f"
      register: files
      changed_when: false
      check_mode: false

    - pause:
        prompt: |-
          Do you want to delete [Y/N]?
            {% for file in files.stdout_lines %}
            {{ file }}
            {% endfor %}
      register: delete
      when: confirm|d(false)|bool

    - file:
        state: absent
        path: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ files.stdout_lines }}"
      when: delete.user_input|d('Y') == 'Y'
```

---

The pattern `/tmp/test/*` will find all files recursively

```bash
Do you want to delete [Y/N]?
    /tmp/test/dir1/x
    /tmp/test/dir1/y
    /tmp/test/dir2/z
    /tmp/test/dir2/x
    /tmp/test/dir2/y
    /tmp/test/file1
    /tmp/test/file2
```

---

Create variable *find_options*. If you want to delete both files and directories set

```yaml
find_options: -type f,d
```

and use the variable in the command

```yaml
    - shell: "find {{ pattern.user_input }} {{ find_options }}"
      register: files
      changed_when: false
      check_mode: false
```

Then, the pattern `/tmp/test/*` will find

```bash
Do you want to delete [Y/N]?
    /tmp/test/dir1
    /tmp/test/dir1/x
    /tmp/test/dir1/y
    /tmp/test/dir2
    /tmp/test/dir2/z
    /tmp/test/dir2/x
    /tmp/test/dir2/y
    /tmp/test/file1
    /tmp/test/file2
```

Comment: Using find is an option perhaps, but then, there are more tasks.  
In this case, i'm quite 'brute-force' deleting the files, but that saves time and is quite valid. I'd rather not let users have input y/n during run. I trust that their input is valid, it's up to them.

Comment: You can easily make the confirmation optional. I updated the code. If it's up to them the confirmation should be turned on in multi-user systems especially if the privilege was escalated, I think.